# What happens when you alter an object retrieved with a getter?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was curious what happens when you try to alter an object retrieved through a `class` `getter`

```
class A {
    constructor () {
        let props = { foo: { hello: 'world' } };

        Object.defineProperty(this, 'foo', {
            get: () => props.foo
        });
    }
}

let a = new A();
    a.foo; // { hello: 'world' }
    a.foo.hello = 2;

    a.foo.hello === 2; // true or false?
```

Comment: Why would you expect this to be any different from any other way of retrieving an object? Objects aren't copied when you retrieve them.

Comment: @Barmar Because nowadays you don't know what restrictions the compiler is going to put in, you should be ashamed of your snarky question

Comment: Compilers don't put arbitrary restrictions on you. In general, statements just do what you tell them to. In Javascript, assigning objects doesn't make copies of them, it assigns references.

Comment: @Barmar Bro, obviously objects are passed by reference, ridiculous that you think I can write JS like this and don't know that. The reason I'm asking is because it's a getter and there is no attached setter. Hence why I'm asking the question

Comment: And they do put restrictions on you, like not being able to set a property on an object that only has a getter for that prop. Or not being able to set a default value when both get and set are defined

Answer (score 0):

Altering properties in the returned object reference will alter the instance's object reference as well

```
class A {
    constructor () {
        let props = { foo: { hello: 'world' } };

        Object.defineProperty(this, 'foo', {
            get: () => props.foo
        });
    }
}

let a = new A();
    a.foo; // { hello: 'world' }
    a.foo.hello = 2;

    a.foo.hello === 2; // true
```

---

Only the directly returned value is immutable and assignment won't change the instance's prop val:

```
a.foo = 'noob'; 
a.foo === 'noob'; // false
```

---